# Node.JS memory deallocation

Tags: node.js, v8

I wrote a simple node server:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer();

var i = 0;
var onRequest = function(req, res){
    res.write('test ' + (++i));
    res.end();
    console.log(i);
};

server.on('request', onRequest);

server.listen(8080);
```

When I started the server, node was using *5.8 MB* of memory, But after serving 100,000 requests, it had memory usage of *21.5 MB*.

**Will this memory be deallocated at some point (when)?**

I'm sure there's no memory leak in the script, it's too simple.

I'm testing on windows 8, localhost.

Comment: what version of Node and V8 are you using?

Comment: I'm using node V0.10.0, so not quite the latest. I don't know how to check which version of V8 it uses, but it was unmodified.

Comment: I updated my answer with how to check the V8 version in node

Comment: I was previously using v8 3.14.5.8, and now since upgrading to node 0.10.10, I have v8 3.14.5.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest version of Node, this memory should be deallocated at some point by V8 and this might be done incrementally.

In previous versions of Node/V8 deallocation was more aggressive and was not done incrementally. The latter wasn't so good for performance.

Have a listen to this http://nodeup.com/fortyfive

You can check the version of V8 node is using like this:

```
node -e "console.log(process.versions.v8)"
```

This post will give you plenty of pointers to check for memory leaks in Node.js
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/11/tracking-down-memory-leaks-in-node-js-a-node-js-holiday-season/

You can also force GC as detailed here: http://simonmcmanus.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/forcing-garbage-collection-with-node-js-and-v8/

Comment: Thanks, It seams upgrading to the latest node/v8 has fixed the problem. After running the same test again, it finished at 13 MB, I could also see the memory fluctuating while running